# VLC won't start automatically at Ubuntu boot

Tags: streaming, vlc, upstart

I am trying to configure VLC to start streaming two streams automatically on boot with Upstart.

Here is my upstart script:

```
description "VLC streams"
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
stop on runlevel [016]
exec /home/streamer/stream.sh
```

and stream.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cvlc -v "/home/administrator/Videos/Kastiel/kastiel.xspf" --sout '#std{access=udp{ttl=2},mux=ts,dst=239.220.220.31:9200}' --sout-keep --loop &
cvlc -v "/home/administrator/Videos/Rozpravky/rozpravky.xspf" --sout '#std{access=udp{ttl=2},mux=ts,dst=239.220.220.2:9200}' --sout-keep --random &
exit 0
```

However, after the computer boots, there is no stream and VLC process is not running. When I run stream.sh manually, it works with no problem.

Does anybody know what mistake am I doing?

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 and VLC 2.0.5.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Milan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vlc doesn't support to be run as root due to security reasons.
You should use **sudo -u user** in script to change the user.

try as :
sudo -u username cvlc -v "/home/administrator/Videos/Kastiel/kastiel.xspf" --sout '#std{access=udp{ttl=2},mux=ts,dst=239.220.220.31:9200}' --sout-keep --loop &